# OLEDB Sum error: Data type mismatch in criteria expression. VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, oledb

Please help!
When I try to sum one column,with two criteria there's an error:

> Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

This is the sql code:

```
 sql1 = "SELECT SUM(quantityofproduct) AS Expr1 FROM (SP001) where year = "2016" AND month = 1"
```

There are 4 columns :

1.ID

2.quantityofproduct

3.Year

4.month

SP001 is the name of the talbe.

I tried it with date column format and &datetimepicker1.value/text& for the criteria but it didn't work.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You want to get sum of `quantityofproduct` when the year and month equal the year and month of `datetimepicker1`

Comment: Is Year a numeric field? If yes, then why do you use a string for the criteria?

Comment: Yes I would like to get the sum of quantityofproduct where the year and month are for example 2016 and 1 (January of 2016)

Comment: Year and Month fields are varchar(30)

Comment: what is the datatype of quantityofproduct?

Comment: A string containing digits is not a number. Number fields and numeric variables  should always be used when you handle numeric values. Allowing the database engine or the VB.NET compiler to convert strings to numbers for you is a secure way to find yourself again in trouble.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if type of fields is varchar(30), you can use quotes '' like this :

```
sql1 = "SELECT SUM(quantityofproduct) AS Expr1 FROM (SP001) where year = '2016' AND month = '1'"
```

But, I advoise you change the type of Column Year and Month to `Integer` and also use Parameter to avoid SQL injection like this :

```
Dim query As String = "SELECT SUM(quantityofproduct) AS Expr1 FROM (SP001) " &
                        "where year = @year And month = @month"
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, connection)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", YearValue)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@month", MonthValue)
Dim sumQuantity As Int32 = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
```

YearValue and MonthValue are the values of year and month searched.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it! Thank you too :)

Comment: This is the problem today again. What type of columns I Have to use?

Comment: You mean `Year` and `Month` column ? and what type of your DataBase, SQL Server or Access ..?

Comment: Access(MDB file). For the year and month column... I Should use decimal type or varchar or else?

Comment: Thank you,but how can I get the sum value?

Comment: You can use `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` like answer

Comment: I tried but theres another error: @year has no default value.

Comment: okay I understand,and it works! Thank you very much !! And sorry for my noob quiestions....

Comment: But now I realize the problem. When I try to sum the 4.th month the error was :Data type mismatch in criteria expression. I write 0 into the empty cells,and the sum worked. Do you know why is it?